# mandatory attributes in HP ALM

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I have written PAF scripts and trying to sync with ALM. It throws an error like **desc and expResult is missing in the activity** How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

All the activities associated with the flow and all tags should be updated with **desc** and **expResult** These are the mandatory attributes “desc” and “expResult”.